# In angular dart, can I find the index in list of strings based on any part of a multi-word criteria

Tags: dart

In angular dart, I have a list of strings that is filled with available groups and a search string. I want to find the index in the list that contains any whole word of the search string. In this example, I would want it to find index 0 because one of the words in the search string "Client" appears in on of the groups. I know the code below will not work because it is looking for the entire searchtext.

```
      List<String> groups = [];
      groups .add('Client Information');
      groups .add('User Information');
      groups .add('Activity Information');

      String searchtext = 'Client Customer';

      return groups.indexWhere((item) => item.contains(searchtext));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically build a RegExp to search for a group of words

```dart
final regExp = RegExp('(${searchtext.replaceAll(' ', '|')})');
final index = groups.indexWhere(regExp.hasMatch);
```